# Replacing an element which has same class naes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 images all within the same class name "image"

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageHolder" style="width: 80%; display:  inline;">
 <div class="image">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/nO2hl.png">
 </div>
 <div class="image">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/IkjJW.png">
 </div>
 <div class="image">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/QrKSV.png">
 </div>
</div>
```

I would like to replace only the 2nd image with a different image link. So I tried something like this:

```
$('.image').find('img').attr('src', 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Smiling_Face_Emoji_with_Blushed_Cheeks_grande.png?v=1480481056');
```

However, this replaces all the images and not just the 2nd one so I tried to do `$('.image')[1].find(..)...`, but that didn't work I was getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[1].find is not a function`.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can please explain what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: because [1] returns the DOM node....

Comment: have a look at [`.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: @Pete Will do, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close - `find()` will return an array and you want your changes to be applied at a **single** element:

```js
$($('.image').find('img')[1]).attr('src', 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Smiling_Face_Emoji_with_Blushed_Cheeks_grande.png?v=1480481056');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageHolder" style="width: 80%; display:  inline;">
 <div class="image">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/nO2hl.png">
 </div>
 <div class="image">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/IkjJW.png">
 </div>
 <div class="image">
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/QrKSV.png">
 </div>
</div>
```

https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Ah okay, I see. Thank you.